# How to get the content of an Excel sheet from OneDrive using Power Automate

Tags: excel, power-automate

I am trying to Copy an excel file that gets uploaded from MS Forms to (automatically goes to OneDrive) to Blob storage using Power Automate.

While my OneDrive (which is the source) **Foldername** is consistent but **File name** keeps changing as new excel files will be uploaded using MS Forms. I am able to get the desired\specific **File name** in Power Automate using trigger action "**Get response details**".

I need to copy that desired excel file from Onedrive location to a Blob storage. since there is no direct option to achieve this (atleast i don't know any direct option), I am using "**List rows present in a table**" to get the content from excel file from Onedrive to **Excel Online**. I am stuck on the what **TableName** option. So, I need to convert the data in excel sheet into table format using "**Create Table**" action so that I can use after this i can use "**List rows present in a table**" to get the file content. Here I am stuck on "**Table Range**" option. Table range might vary for my excel sheet. **How can I get the Table Range dynamically?**

[image]

Once I get this "**Table Range**" thing working in "**Create Table**", then I can use "**List rows present in a table**" thing and I know how to Blob using "Create Blob (V2)" action.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I have to do "**Create Table**" followed by "**List Rows present in a Table**".

[image]